# Why is this Haskell array-code not working?

Tags: arrays, haskell

I have tried this code in Haskell :

```
array :: (Ix a) => (a,a) -> [(a,b)] -> Array a b
squares = array (1,100) [(i, i*i) | i <- [1..100]]
```

But when i run that Code i get this message by GHCi:

```
The type signature for array lacks an accompanying binding
      (The type signature must be given where array is declared)
```

What exactly is meant with accompanying binding and how to fix that?

Comment: Your type annotation is for a thing called `array`, but your function is called `squares`. It looks like you should delete the type signature for `array` and import it from `Data.Array`, then possibly add an annotation for `squares`.

Answer (score 3):

Because you define a type signature **for [`array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/array/latest/doc/html/Data-Array-IArray.html#v:array)**, not `squares` (`array` is a library function, you cannot *redefine* it, you can of course *write your own*). Now the compiler thinks you aim to define your own `array` and says: "*Got that, but where is your function definition?*" it thus lacks a *binding* (implementation so to speak).

The **binding is thus its implementation** (here `squares = array (1,100) [(i, i*i) | i <- [1..100]]`). Furthermore between brackets the compiler also says that you cannot define the function where you want, it must be in the file where the function signature is (the **signature** is where you define its type so `:: (Ix a) => (a,a) -> [(a,b)] -> Array a b`).

Given you meant to give a signature to `squares`, the **type signature is too broad**. The most generic type signature is:

```
squares :: (Enum e, Num e, Ix e) => Array e e
squares = array (1,100) [(i, i*i) | i <- [1..100]]
```

Comment: The OP’s type signature actually *is* the type signature for `array` from `Data.Array`, not `squares`.

Comment: @AlexisKing: well that is the first point (the one why it crashes).

Comment: Right, I’m just saying I don’t think “define your type signature too broad” is meaningful, since it doesn’t look like the type signature provided was intended for `squares` at all.

Comment: @AlexisKing: well I was only giving a heads up that simply changing the name will not resolve the issue, otherwise within three minutes there is a new question. I don't think we should generate sequences of small problems we solve.

Comment: @AlexisKing: rewrote it. Better?

Comment: Thanks to you both :)